# Problemas al iniciar el xampp, ssh no accecible

Tags: xampp, macos

Buen día, me pueden ayudar como solucionar este problema, de la nada se puso asi el programa y no puedo acceder a las carpetas.

***Este es el error:***

```
INFO: Iniciando la pila "XAMPP"
ERROR: Error al iniciar la pila "XAMPP": no se puede iniciar la pila: ssh no accesible
```

[image: Error que me sale en el xampp]

Comment: ¿Qué otro error te marca? Me refiero a que si ya configuraste el puerto para trabajar en ssh?

Comment: solo me marca ese error, desde que lo instale no le he cambiado el puerto, de la nada se puso asi

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes configurado los puertos? Puedes mostrar la pestaña de "Network", por favor. Y tambien agrega que version de Mac estas usando.

Comment: claro, tengo
 localhost:8080 -> 80(Over SSH)
 localhost:8443 -> 443(Over SSH), macOS catalina, version 10.15.6 beta

Comment: Al parecer son problemas de los puertos. Por lo que leo, Apache viene pre-instalado y ya configurado con esos puerto. Es por ello que, cuando instalas xampp, los puertos ya están ocupados. Intenta cambiar los puertos para que funcione.

Comment: Te comparto este link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582504/xampp-apache-webserver-localhost-not-working-on-mac-os puede ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Hola leyendo por ahí me tope con esta info. Espero te sea de utilidad:

## Xampp y MacOS

De acuerdo a este [Blog sobre xampp-VM para Mac](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html), al parecer XAMMP para Mac se ejecuta en una máquina virtual aislada. Esta "máquina virtual" es un entorno de software que mantiene XAMMP (es decir, sus procesos, tales como Apache) independiente del sistema operativo del host (MacOS).

**La razón de reenvío de puertos en el XAMMP de interfaz parece ser debido a cualquier puerto por debajo de `1024` se considera un puerto privilegiado en NIX** (como la de Mac y linux).

Estos "Puertos privilegiados" (para este caso) se manejan como procesos (por ejemplo httpd.exe Apache) que necesita ser ejecutado como "root" para que se una a ella.

Para evitar que toques puertos en el sistema MacOS para configurar xampp, los desarrolladores de Apache Friends proporcionan una conexión al servidor web en un puerto "no privilegiado" `8080`.

## ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Tienes algunas opciones

- Asegurarte de que el firewall de tu maquina virtual no este bloqueando el puerto `80` y/o el puerto `8080`.
- Puedes deshabilitar la instalación por defecto de Apache semi-permanente (este puedes tomarlo como un ultimo recurso.
- Configurar el reenvío de puerto `80` al puerto `8080`. La otra opción puede ser la de adelante de puerto entrante 80 a 8080 a `Your_Mac_IP` en el router para la red (aqui depende de cómo has configurado la red).

Fuentes: [Blog de apache friends](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20170628.html)